# PHPBB Ajax External Login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forum, phpbb

I'm having some issues trying to get an external login for PHPBB to work with AJAX. I'm not really sure what I'm missing here, so here's what I got:

HTML:

```
<div id="dialogin" class="dialoghide" title="Loading...">
    <form id="loginformadj" name="loginformadj" action="forum/ucp.php?mode=login" method="post" data-ajax="true" data-refresh="false">
        <h3><a id="dialoglogin" href="forum/ucp.php?mode=login" data-ajax="true">Login</a>&nbsp; &bull; &nbsp;
        <a id="dialogregister" href="forum/ucp.php?mode=register" data-ajax="true">Register</a></h3>
        <fieldset id="userinfo">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="10" title="Username" />
            <label for="password">Password:</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="10" title="Password" />
            <label for="autologin">Log me on automatically<input type="checkbox" name="autologin" id="autologin" /></label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="submit-buttons">
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="./index.php" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS included on page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // handle the login form through ajax for phpbb
    $('#loginformadj').on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var url= $(this).attr('action');
        alert(url);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'HTML',
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data, status) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is required at the top of the page from another file where I use phpbb sessions and other functions:

```
<?php
/*
 * BEGIN PHPBB STANDARD PAGE SETUP
 */
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = './forum/';
$website_root_path = './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);

include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
//include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_module.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();
/*
 * END PHPBB STANDARD PAGE SETUP
 */
?>
```

The form is pulled into a jquery dialog box. It does in fact log me in, then it immediately redirects me to the forum index at ./forum instead of using the ajax and sending the alerts. I don't get any of the alerts I've set or anything. I've tried everything I can think of. :/

To add, I have the username, user avatar, and can logout all on my external page as well. Just can't get the login to work at all.

Comment: Anyone? I'm at a serious loss of ideas here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, at least initially, was I was calling the forum submission check for jquery wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// handle the login form through ajax for phpbb
$(document).on('submit', '#login', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var url= $(this).attr('action');
    alert(url);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
});
```

I also read that you need the sid called with $user->data in a hidden field. I included that in the form and didn't check if it mattered or not.